# How to parse an ETag for use inside If-None-Match header

Tags: http, header, rss, etag

I have tried obtaining an ETag from various urls (RSS feeds), and obatained a different format for each one

`W/"2c34-Lgd4oF7wqtfEvHc5kEphPr/7eaY"`

`W/"159a-VcHeTnlFfRm4lQABXPoMZNXbNSM"`

`o0Vn/cflaoT/ZhtK8pK+HPNXGAE` (No quotes)

`"80238bdb1dced51:0"` (Quotes included)

`kPn9GRCk70fI0HGuT3Yop7WU6DU` (No quotes)

Can I use them all in an `If-None-Match` header the same way they were provided, do I need to add/remove quotes or maybe remove the `W/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `ETag` and `If-None-Match` is defined in [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#appendix-C).

You'll see that the two headers use the same `entity-tag` reference; that is, the complete value for `ETag` (including quotes and `W/`) should be used in `If-None-Match`.

Now, the two responses that don't include the quotes are not syntactically valid. That said, I'm sure that browsers and such make accommodations for that case. You'll have to decide whether to mirror them exactly and produce an invalid `If-None-Match` header, or to add quotes. It's very likely that either will work equally well in practice.

Comment: Thanks, funnily enough some websites provide a syntactically correct ETag yet don't implement `If-None-Match` (`"80238bdb1dced51:0"` format from aljazeera.com); at least `If-Not-Modified-Since` works on it